# How can I rewrite the following problem in ADMM form?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a problem like this

$
\mathop {\max }\limits_{\mathbf{x}_n,\boldsymbol{y}_n} \;\;f(\mathbf{x}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{x}_N,\mathbf{y}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{y}_N) \\
 s.t.\;\;\\
\mathbf{x}_1+\cdots+\mathbf{x}_n=\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^K,\\
\mathbf{y}_1=\mathbf{y}_2=\cdots=\mathbf{y}_N\\
0\le\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_n\le1,n=1,\cdots,N,
$

where $f$ is a continuous differentiable function of $\mathbf{x}_n$ and $\mathbf{y}_n$. **In addition, $f$ can be rewritten as $f=\sum_{n=1}^N a_ng(\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_n)$ with $g$ is a continuous differentiable function of $\mathbf{x}_n$ and $\mathbf{y}_n$, and $0\le a_n\le 1$**

I think it may be solved by using ADMM. However, after studying this method, I find that ADMM needs a constraint like as $A\mathbf{x}+B\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{c}$ with $A$ and $B$ being full column rank.

Can anyone give me some clues to transform the problem into a ADMM form?

Comment: Does $f$ have any further structure such as being separable?

Comment: Yes, I added a statement in the problem as **$f$ can be rewritten as $f=\sum_{n=1}^N a_ng(\mathbf{x}_n,\mathbf{y}_n)$ with $g$ is a continuous differentiable function of $\mathbf{x}_n$ and $\mathbf{y}_n$, and $0\le a_n\le 1$**

Comment: Why don't you include the equality constraint on $y_{i}$'s into the objective? There will be fewer variables to optimize over..